# Remove parent element using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Here is an attempt to remove parent div. Why it doesn't work?

```js
var images = document.querySelector('.gallery');
images.addEventListener('click', removeClickedImage);

const hasClass = (el, test) => el.classList.contains(test);
const removeClickedImage = ({ target }) => {
    if (hasClass(target, 'remove')) {
        target.parentNode.remove();
    }
};
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="foo.jpg">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="bar.png">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You are trying to use `removeClickedImage` before you defined it.

Comment: Define the function removeClickedImage() before images.addEventListener

Comment: Did you look in the console to see the errors there?  They even show in the snippet in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `const` functions (along with anything else initialized with `const` or `let`) do not get hoisted: at the moment you add the listener, `removeClickedImage` has not been defined yet. Add the listener *after* the function has been defined, and it works just fine. The only time you can rely on hoisting like that is when the variable in question is a function defined via a *function declaration*, like `function fnName() {`.

```js
  const hasClass = (el, test) => el.classList.contains(test);
  const removeClickedImage = ({
    target
  }) => {
    if (hasClass(target, 'remove')) {
      target.parentNode.remove();
    }
  };

  var images = document.querySelector('.gallery');
  images.addEventListener('click', removeClickedImage);
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
  <div class="image">
    <img src="foo.jpg">
    <button class="remove">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="image">
    <img src="bar.png">
    <button class="remove">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Big thanks. I know, it's completely out of scope of this question, but how it could be modified to work without event listener, instantly? Of course, `removeClickedImage();` at the bottom of the file doesn't work, because it's not a function.

Comment: What do you mean, `instantly`? Listeners activate immediately. It would be possible to accomplish something similar using CSS and hidden checkboxes, but that's a *very* hacky solution that shouldn't be used. Javascript *is* the right tool for the job here

Comment: Here is what I mean: https://jsfiddle.net/a1tez3r1/. You just run the script, and there is no need to click any elements to see an alert.

Comment: Why not just remove the images from the HTML then,  if you want them to be removed immediately? Or you could just remove the `.gallery` div. You could also iterate over all `image` divs, but that's a tiny bit messier.

Comment: No, this is just example. In real life, it will be part of userscript. It would catch all divs appeared when I scroll the browser window and remove them. The divs itself loaded on scroll, via AJAX. If such div contain visited link, it should be removed. I already tried different ways for it.

Comment: Use MutationObserver to listen for changes to the `.gallery`, and when it gets populated with `image`s, remove them.

Answer (score 2):

you have to declare the function before calling it when you use `const`, see :  [Cant access lexical declaration before init](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init)

```js
const removeClickedImage = ({ target }) => {
    if (hasClass(target, 'remove')) {
        target.parentNode.remove();
    }
};

var images = document.querySelector('.gallery');
images.addEventListener('click', removeClickedImage);

const hasClass = (el, test) => el.classList.contains(test);
```

```html
<div class="gallery">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="foo.jpg">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img src="bar.png">
        <button class="remove">x</button>
    </div>
</div>
```